# What is the alternative for the deprecated Pandas.Panel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, deprecated

FutureWarning: 
Panel is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
The recommended way to represent these types of 3-dimensional data are with a MultiIndex on a DataFrame, via the Panel.to_frame() method.

I am getting the above error whenever i ran this code!
`difference = pd.Panel(dict(df1=df1,df2=df2))`
Can anyone please tell me the alternative way for usage of Panel with the above line of code.

Edit-1:-

```
def report_diff(x):
   return x[0] if x[0] == x[1] else '{} ---> {}'.format(*x)

difference = pd.Panel(dict(df1=df1,df2=df2))
res = difference.apply(report_diff, axis=0)
```

Here df1 and df2 contains both categorical and numerical data.
Just comparing the two dataframes here to get the differences between the two.

Comment: Can you provide sample inputs and outputs? See: Creating a [mcve]

Comment: @G.Anderson i have provided sample code of my program. Can you please provide me the replacement for panel.

Comment: Note, that is not an error, that is a *warning*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [stated in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Panel.html), the recommended replacements for a Pandas Panel are using a multindex, or the `xarray` library.

For your specific use case, this somewhat hacky code gets you the same result:

```
a = df1.values.reshape(df1.shape[0] * df1.shape[1])
b = df2.values.reshape(df2.shape[0] * df2.shape[1])
res = np.array([v if v == b[idx] else str(v) + '--->' + str(b[idx]) for idx, v in enumerate(a)]).reshape(
    df1.shape[0], df1.shape[1])
res = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=df1.columns)
```

Comment: I tried, i dono what i'm missing. But can you please show how to use xarray in place of panel.!!for the above code

Comment: I would be happy to, if you could provide a longer example

Comment: i have provide an snippet in my edit. can you provide what can be used in place of panel.

Comment: I've provided something of an answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Josh Friedlander.